# How to open any file(pdf, doc) INSIDE a browser without open/save dialog in java

Tags: java, jquery, pdf, iframe, doc

i have tried it with iframe works well only for pdf(but save option will be disable through browser settings only) can any one give an idea, about this. (Is there any open source plugins.)

Comment: server side Java..also javascript (like plugins) if any possibilities are there! @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 0):

You could try [pdfObject](http://pdfobject.com/examples/index.php). There are some good examples.

Comment: i know that one but it does not disable save option at cleint side. Iam looking for a solution which display all types of documents in client browser without save option. not only PDF

Answer (score 0):

Try PDFjs, it uses HTML5 to draw the pdf

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/